# How to break out of an infinite loop in emacs lisp ? (environment: emacs)

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I tried using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> then :a

But It doesn't work here.

My code is like:

```
(defun game-repl()
    (loop (print (eval (read)))))
```

then I run

```
(game-repl())
look()
```

Comment: Often game loops will have a variable `isDone` or `isNotDone`, and will loop based on that, e.g. `(while is-not-done ... )`.  Simply set `is-not-done` to false, and the loop will break on the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you @Merlyn, But my question is how to break this loop back to my Lisp programming enviroment,that is emacs.

Comment: Hence why a comment and not an answer :)  But it would solve the problem... Just set `is-not-done` in your REPL.  But yes I can see you are looking for an editor command, not a programmable solution.

Comment: Thank you Merlyn. I see. I searched some sources. You are right. I need to "tell" lisp when to get out. ;)

Comment: `(Game-repl ())` should signal an error because of an invalid number of arguments (expects none, but gets one).  `Look` is most likely not a defined variable.  `()` evaluates to `nil`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(require 'cl)
(loop (setq x (read))
      (if (eq x 'exit)
        (return)
        (print (eval x))))
```

Answer (score 6):

Emacs modes often send an interruption signal to the inferior program only when you hit Ctrl-C twice in a row (i.e., the key sequence you are looking for is `C-c C-c`).  In particular, this is true for [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/).

This is because `C-c` is a [prefix key](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html) that is usually combined with other keys to access a whole bunch of mode-specific features.

Answer (score 2):

[Reference http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter05.html]

Most of the time you write a LOOP form, you'd like to have a way out. Fortunately, a RETURN form anywhere inside will cause control to leave the LOOP; any value you specify becomes the value of the LOOP form:

```
 ? (loop
     (print "Here I am.")
     (return 17)
     (print "I never got here."))
 "Here I am."
 17
```

RETURN is normally used in a conditional form, like this:

```
? (let ((n 0))
     (loop
       (when (> n 10) (return))
  (print n) (print (* n n))
  (incf n)))

0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
NIL
?
```

Answer (score 2):

This question can refer to:

1. how to programmatically break out of a loop that would otherwise be infinite or
2. how to manually stop an infinite loop that's already raging.

The 1st has satisfactorily been answered by @fred-foo (and it seems it was OP's actual question). The 2nd has been tackled by @matthias-benkard but his answer is not working for emacs lisp.

The actual answer to manually stop a running infinite emacs-lisp loop is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (C-g in emacs-speak).

There is a documentation page in the [emacs lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Infinite-Loops.html) on this very topic.

Sorry, I don't have the reputation to just amend @matthias-benkard's answer and the question ranks high on search engines...

Answer (score -1):

This Stack Exchange answer is the first hit on google for "break a never ending loop slime"

```
 C-c C-b
```

What is missing, is that different lisps handle this break differently. I found this answer because GNU Clisp just doesn't intercept SLIME's C-c C-b. Nor does it do what SBCL does which is intercept both C-c C-b and C-c C-c.

Comment: I've just confirmed that this is specific to Clisp on Windows.